# Treeview column chooser devexpress asp.net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Due to a lot of columns to chose from, the standard column selector in Devexpress doesn't cut it for me. So I thought of something like a "grouped" column chooser. This should work like a treeview with expandable "main nodes" showing all columns under the main node.

Here is a visual representation of what i mean:

[image]

Clicking on any of the Category buttons should expand the clicked button and show all columns underneath. From that point, it should be possible to drag columns into the grid just as in the standard column chooser.

I've researched in the [documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView#column-chooser) but there is no mention of anything like that. 
So my question is:

**is there even a possibility to implement this in ASPNET Webforms?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the desired behaviour with the built-in Column choser in ASPxGridView. The only way to accomplish the task are the following steps:

1. Create a new dialog in which you can show the corresponding tree view structure in ASPxPopupControl
2. Change the visibility of grid columns using the ASPxClientGridView.MoveColumn(column)